# Collision Energy for heavy ions

Tags: particle-physics, collision, accelerator-physics, particle-accelerators

I found this formula in Sahoo Relativistic Kinematics:
$$\sqrt{s_{NN}}=2\sqrt{s_{pp}}+\sqrt{s_{pp}}\sqrt{\frac{Z_{1}Z_{2}}{A_{1}A_{2}}}$$
But because English isn't my first language i got confused. So $\sqrt{s_{NN}}$ is energy per colliding nucleon. $\sqrt{s_{pp}}$ is corresponding energy for proton proton collision. So how do i go from here? For example i want particular collisional energy per nucleon. And in experiment with fixed target. How do i find energy of bombarding ions?

Comment: I asked a question related to this (https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/600966/how-is-the-nucleus-nucleus-cm-energy-per-nucleon-related-the-proton-proton-cm-en). I'm starting to think that this equation is just wrong.

Comment: Also related to this: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/605657/how-is-s-nn-defined