# How is the nucleus-nucleus CM energy per nucleon related the proton-proton CM energy in a circular accelerator?

Tags: reference-frames, large-hadron-collider, accelerator-physics, heavy-ion

If I understand it correctly, the center of mass energy per nucleon pair in heavy ion collisions is given by $$\sqrt{s_{NN}}=\sqrt{(p_a/A_a+p_b/A_b)^2},$$ where $a$ and $b$ label each colliding nuclei, $p_k$ are their 4-momenta, and the $A_k$ are their mass number. In the high energy limit ($E\approx p\gg m$) one can get that $$\sqrt{s_{NN}}\approx 2 \sqrt{\frac{E_aE_b}{A_aA_b}}.$$

Assuming the energy of a nucleus is $Z$ times the energy a proton reaches in the same accelerator ($E_p$), then $$\sqrt{s_{NN}}\approx2E_p\sqrt{\frac{Z_a Z_b}{A_aA_b}},$$ which can be rewritten as $$\sqrt{s_{NN}}\approx\sqrt{s_{pp}}\sqrt{\frac{Z_a Z_b}{A_aA_b}}$$ where $\sqrt{s_{pp}}$ is the CM energy for two colliding protons.

What am I missing to arrive to the first equation of [0907.1219](https://arxiv.org/abs/0907.1219) or to equation 54 of [1604.02651](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.02651)? That equation reads $$\sqrt{s_{NN}}\approx2\sqrt{s_{pp}}+\sqrt{s_{pp}}\sqrt{\frac{Z_a Z_b}{A_aA_b}}.$$

Moreover, trying to particularize this equation to a proton-proton collision, where $A_a=A_b=Z_a=Z_b=1$, one gets $\sqrt{s_{NN}}=3\sqrt{s_{pp}}$, which seems inconsistent. Why/where are either the author of [1](https://arxiv.org/abs/0907.1219) or me confused?

In this [CERN document](http://dx.doi.org/10.5170/CERN-2014-006.167) (eq. 1), one can see a result matching the one I calculate here. Which one is correct?

Comment: Related question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/597965/collision-energy-for-heavy-ions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at more papers dealing with these issues, I found [1108.5438](https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.5438), which contains (in eq. 2) the expression $$\sqrt{s_{NN}}\approx 2cp_\mathrm{proton}\sqrt{\frac{Z_1Z_2}{A_1A_2}},$$ which matches the result in the OP. This paper is authored by the author of the first paper cited in the OP, but two years later, which suggests that the author might have made a mistake in the original paper to later realize that it was wrong.

Regarding the other paper cited in the OP, it is possible that the author got that mistakenly from existing literature.

Unless anyone finds this erroneous, I will keep my own answer as the correct answer.